# Can't start applications on Microsoft Android emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, android-emulator

Try to start application on Microsoft Android Emulator. On KitKat platform can't launch default browser. it hanged in 1 min and don't start. I've tried other applications (dolphin browser for example), situation is the same.   On any other platform everything is working. I have windows 2012 server r2 with 8 GB RAM. I've used all Kitkat devices. 
Here is screenshots [first](http://clip2net.com/s/3nVQuPw) [second](http://clip2net.com/s/3nVQfxW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have Windows Audio Service (Services > Windows Audio) enabled in Windows Server 2012 the emulator will fail to run some apps.

This is fixed in an update that will be available very soon.